# If I format my hard-disk ,will I be able to create another totally new partition.I want to use it for dual booting

Tags: partitioning

If I format my hard drive with "disk" application from the applications in ubuntu 20.04 ,then will I be able have another partition .I am looking for to dual boot with Windows 10 and I want to create a totally new partition for dual booting,manually,without having to reinstall ubuntu 20.04 again ,or can i update ubuntu 20.04 and get me partions more than two,or,I think, I have read some "article" about updating ubuntu and to get more than two partitions that way,but can it be done manually,or disk partitioning is a different thing altogether,and formatting disk with "disk" application of the applications in ubuntu 20.04 will not help.I am new to linux and absolute beginner when it comes to formatting hard-disk.I didn't go for more partitions than two while installing ubuntu.

Comment: If you only have one hard drive with Ubuntu on it, Do Not Format.  See how much free/unused space you have on your Ubuntu partition.  Windows will need 30GBs or more free space.  You will need the USB stick with Ubuntu installer on it or make new one.  Boot into USB stick and shrink Ubuntu partition enough for Windows, if you have enough free space.  If Ubuntu partition is more than half full, be careful unless it is a big drive, 500GB to 1TB.

Comment: I will slow to answer please stay.

Comment: i have only two partitions ...two devices....file system of those two are efi and ext4 ...should i use gparted to change file system  of efi one whose mount point is '/boot/efi' and then shrink ext4 whose mount point is '/' using gpated ,shrink using gparted's options ....help

Comment: Do not touch EFI.  You will need to decide if there is enough unused space on /.  Can only shrink / from USB stick.  Cannot do it from Ubuntu itself.  Installing an OS(Ubuntu/Windows) or working on partitions can lead to data lost, should have important data back up.  If no data would suggest to install Windows first and then re install Ubuntu,  give each OS around half of drive(more or less to your liking)

Comment: efi is  a partition..?

Comment: A small partition, do not touch.  It allows you to boot into Ubuntu and/or Windows.  How much free or unused space on your Ubuntu partition?

Comment: i understood you...how to shrink ubuntu from usb stick...i tried unmounting ext4 ... the 987 gb one but ....it is busy.......................in ext4(987 gb) windows and ubuntu will be there ....987gb is one partition

Comment: i mean mean i cant have two OSes in partition ..it will break everything...how to shrink ubuntu from usb...help

Comment: i have backed my data ...can i format with 'disk' tool to add a new partition...or can i add a new partition by updating 20.04 to 20.11 and  shrinking doesnt work either here with gparted..i think this is what you are saying .....

Comment: Boot to USB stick.  Use gparted on USB, might have to unmount / partition if it is mounted, then shrink and make new partition(can format new partition as NTFS) to install Windows to.  Formatting removes all data on disk or partition.  It is Not used to make/add partitions

Comment: so you suggest reinstalling..cant format because there will be no ubuntu and cant do dual booting ....no way out once you....only way in to the problem if you don't manual partition enough partitions at ubuntu installing times.

Comment: Can shrink Ubuntu partition from USB stick using gparted. Then can install Windows on new partition.  Must use USB Ubuntu installer to work on Ubuntu partition.  Do not need to use formatting.  Format is wrong thing to use to make partitions.

Comment: the ''new'' option ...of gparted ?...ooo

Comment: just boot to installing media ....huh

Comment: Windows in UEFI mode wants lots of partitions. Just make unallocated space for Windows to use. Be sure to boot Windows installer in UEFI mode. It should use same ESP - efi system partition you already have but will create more partitions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Answer (score 0):

Formatting a disk wipes the entire partition table.

A formatted disk will functionally behave like a brand new hard drive, although there are some technical differences.  For example, if you quick format a HDD, it doesn't actually erase data, even though it is effectively gone.

Formatting a disk will not allow you to continue using any existing operating system on that disk and you will need to reinstall Ubuntu.  If you don't want to reinstall Ubuntu, your path is going to be more complicated and as a new user you may prefer to keep things as simple as possible.

To make it easier, I suggest that you allow the Windows 10 and Ubuntu installers to do the bulk of work for setting up the new partitions.

You can help the installers do this automatically and also set the size for each OS by using the Disks app to create two partitions as placeholders for each operating system.  Delete the respective placeholder partition before beginning an installation.

Here's an example workflow: If you format a 1 TB hard drive (GPT), you can create a 700 GB partition for Windows and a 300 GB partition for Ubuntu. It doesn't matter what filesystem you choose. Before installing Windows, use Disks to remove the 700 GB partition so there is unallocated free space. Then boot the Windows installer as UEFI and select that free space for Windows. A typical Windows 10 install will create ~4 partitions automatically within the confines of that 700 GB of unallocated space.  When the Windows install is finished, use Disks again to remove the 300 GB partition and then boot the Ubuntu installer as UEFI.  You will get an automated option to "Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows".

Comment: ''A typical Windows 10 install will create ~4 partitions automatically within the confines of that 700 GB of unallocated space. When the Windows install is finished, use Disks again to remove the 300 GB partition and then boot the Ubuntu installer as UEFI.''....''Delete the respective placeholder partition before beginning an installation''......''Formatting a disk will not allow you to continue using any existing operating system on that disk and you will need to reinstall Ubuntu''.....i used to think about formatting differently.

Comment: so you suggest reinstalling..cant format because there will be no ubuntu and cant do dual booting ....no way out once you....only way in to the problem if you don't enough partitions at ubuntu installing times.